# How to display custom text message on top of "Proceed to Checkout" button using custom module in magento2

Tags: php, magento2

So what I am trying to display the custom message on top of my cart page "Proceed to Checkout" button.
Like below:
[image]

However **the problem is, my custom module content is not displaying.** My code is as below:
Custom Module name: PaymentAdBlock

```
Ext/Block/PaymentAdBlock.php look like below:

<?php

namespace PaymentAdBlock\Ext\Block;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link;

class PaymentAdBlock extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link {
// This function is created for testing purpose, you can add more function as per your requirement
public function getTest(){
    return 'Test Button';
}
} 

?>
```

My Ext/etc/module.xml look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="PaymentAdBlock_Ext" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

My Ext/view/frontend/layout/cart_view.xml file look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block class="PaymentAdBlock\Ext\Block\PaymentAdBlock" name="paymentadblock" template="PaymentAdBlock_Ext::custom_link.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

My Ext/view/templates/custom_link.phtml file look like below:

```
I am coming here....
<?php
/**
 * custom ad block.
 * 
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link */
?>
<?php echo $block->getTest();?>
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()) :?>
    custom block coming here.....
    <?php echo $block->getTest();?>
    <button type="button"
            data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>"
            data-mage-init='{
                "Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{
                    "checkoutUrl":"<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getCheckoutUrl())) ?>"
                }
            }'
            class="action primary checkout<?= ($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : '' ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isDisabled()) :?>
                disabled="disabled"
            <?php endif; ?>>
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?></span>
    </button>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: can anyone please help? thanks in advance:)

Comment: Hi, @Jimil please check with this method? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187116/84495